ffmpeg `-ss` with `-frame_pts true` give wrong pts for file name
when I put -ss in front of -i then the frame's pts expand correct
ffmpeg -ss 674 -i input.ts -vf "select=not(mod(n\,1)),setpts=PTS+674/TB"  -vsync vfr -frame_pts true -r 1000 -vframes 40 /tmp/out_frames/frame_%08d.png

the file name has some offset:
frame_00675000.png
frame_00675033.png
frame_00675067.png
frame_00675100.png
...

however, if I put -ss after -i I suppose it means it will keep decoding and ditch packets until the point that the start time reached, it will start to encode.
I guess in this case the packet's PTS will not actually change, so in theory I do not need to add any offset by setpts:
ffmpeg -i input.ts -ss 674 -vf "select=not(mod(n\,1))"  -vsync vfr -frame_pts true -r 1000 -vframes 40 /tmp/out_frames/frame_%08d.png

The resulting frame is actually correct, but the frame name start from 0, which is strange.
If I add the setpts the frame is completly wrong, because it think the first frame is already offset to 674.
ffmpeg -i input.ts -ss 674 -vf "select=not(mod(n\,1)),setpts=PTS+674/TB"  -vsync vfr -frame_pts true -r 1000 -vframes 40 /tmp/out_frames/frame_%08d.png

I wonder what is the correct way to do this? the result confused me a lot:

if -vf take effect before the -ss waiting logic then the -ss should not really change the PTS
if the -vf take effect after the -ss the waiting logic should not be affect the setpts

but apparently both command failed to get correct result.

The exact logic when FFmpeg passes or modifies the timestamps seems complicated. Instead of -ss you may use trim filter: ffmpeg -i input.ts -vf "trim=674,select=not(mod(n\,1))" -vsync vfr -frame_pts true -r 1000 -vframes 40 /tmp/out_frames/frame_%08d.png.
